# How to change menu style in Android 4.x devices with menu button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I found a problem that I've changed actionbar overflow style in my app, when I make it's selector color change from blue to orange.

Some Android 4.x devices still have a menu button, when I click it, it's option list won't jump out from actionbar overflow, but from screen's bottom. For this kind of situation, it's option list won't change according to my style (selector color: orange).

How can I change the style for this kind of menu list?

Comment: This is really annoying. I'm running into this with the Samsung Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below code..?

```
private void getOverflowMenu() {

    try {
       ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
       Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
       if(menuKeyField != null) {
           menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
           menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

Call this method at Application level, may it'll work for you..